# What Sort of Discovery Warrants Writing a Paper

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

I am a high school student who is deeply passionate about mathematics and I have written many different mathematical proofs. I was wondering what sort of discovery warrants writing a mathematical paper for publication. Does the amount of content matter, or the significance of the discovery? Any advice you can give would be appreciated. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: A mathematician send a paper to a journal. When he/she gets the answer of the editors: "It is a paper with original and important results. Unfortunately the original ones are not important and the important ones are not original". Of course, not accepted. It's just a joke. The significance of the results is much more important than the amount of content.

Comment: Is there a university anywhere near you? Try to contact the math department, and see whether there is anyone there happy to take a look at what you've done, and to give you advice.

Comment: I once got a comment back from referee "A" describing my paper as "the ultimate orgy of irrelevant detail." Although other referees accepted it for publication, I considered the matter and decided that referee A was right.  I withdrew the paper...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any field (well, at least in math and physics, the two fields I am interested in) one of the skills acquired over time by a serious researcher is a feel for what problems are open, what problems are interesting enough to be published, who is currently working on what, and so forth.  In general, one doesn't have this fell until at least the second year of grad school.

The knowledge is acquired by reading journal papers and discussions with professors.  Until you have reached upper-level undergraduate work at the least, you might not have the sophistication to appreciate and follow the journal papers you can get your hands on.  That is why this feel does not often come early.

That said, there are (in Math, but not so much in phsyics) journals that are of high quality yet are more accessible to the younger set.  There are some journals published by the MAA; Journal of Recreational Mathematics has some papers that don't require a Ph. D. to understand, Mathematical Intelligencer is excellent.  If you read the latter, for example, and think your work is on par with the articles you find there, by all means format your work in the way those articles appear (there will be style guides for each journal) and send it in.  Unless you have some really super result, you will have to spend the time to worry about formatting, air-tight proofs, and saying things in good English.   Try to find a journal (perhaps an electronic journal if necessary) that does not demand page charges; those are more common today than in the past.

Also, you might do well by asking on a site like this or MathOverflow qestions like
"I have proven that $\zeta(3)$ is transcendental; is this a known result and is it important enough to publish if it isn't?" 
Some really solid mathematicians visit here, and somebody like Robert Israel may well give you a solid answer to such a question.

Last piece of advice:  If you have attacked a question that is known to be "hard" and think you have solved it, chances are that there is a flaw in your work.  If you can collaborate with somebody capable of finding such flaws, it is worth it.